# UIImageJPEGRepresentation fills Memory

Tags: ios, memory-management

The code below pumps the memory to the limit. I loaded about 100 Images and the memory went to 200MB. If I put the app in background and foreground, than it purge the memory from 200MB to around 10MB. How can I release the memory? The @autoreleasepool didn't work

```
@autoreleasepool {
        NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
        NSString *name    = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
        NSString *path    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.jpg", name];
        NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
        if ([imgData writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES]) {
            data.imagePath = path;
            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];
        } else {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                        message:@"There was an error saving your photo. Try again."
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        }
        imgData = nil;
}
```

Comment: You can use performSelectorInBackground or did you try calling didReceiveMemoryWarning when you are done with loading images onto the view?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning)]; is a private method, but it solves the problem. I can't use it. Call UIImageJPEGRepresentation in a background thread did not solve the problem